# What turmite runs the longest before becoming predictable?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, open-problem, turing-machines, cellular-automata

When looking at 2D Turing machines, many of them eventually become predictable. For example, Langton's Ant, the champion 2-color 1-state turmite, develops a highway after 10,000 steps. Predictable behavior includes Traps (as in Worm Trails), Highways, Spirals, Wedges and Sequences (like the binary counter). Examples at [2D Turing Machines](http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_06_07_04.html), within [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net/), and at wikipedia's [Turmite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmite) entry.

For 2-color, 2-state Turmites, {{{1,1,1},{0,8,1}},{{1,8,1},{0,1,0}}} found by Georgi Gochev runs for 240 million steps before becoming predictable.

[image: {{{1,1,1},{0,8,1}},{{1,8,1},{0,1,0}}} found by Georgi Gochev]

EDIT: Beating that is {{{1,8,1},{0,2,0}},{{1,8,0},{0,1,0}}}, with
7.735 billion timesteps before making a wedge: (Georgi Gochev)

EDIT: Beating that is {{{0,1,1},{0,4,0}},{{1,4,0},{1,2,1}}}, with 9.533 trillion timesteps before making a highway (found by Mark Jeronimus).

Is that the longest unpredictable run for a 2-color, 2-state termite?

[Non-halting Busy Beaver](https://github.com/GollyGang/ruletablerepository/wiki/EdPeggsBusyBeaverTurmiteChallenge#unresolved-turmites) is a repository for known results.